# Unable to login with passport js and no errors are being generated?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, passport.js

I am unable to use my passportjs login system.

I have created a login page with React and the same has been converted to the production build. Now, I am trying to login from that production build of the react page. I am using nodejs on the backend with the passportjs. When I type correct username or password nothing happens. No errors are generated anywhere.

Here is my backend code: -

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
dotenv.config();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//For serving of static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//-----------------Passport strategy and imports-----------------------------
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const session = require('express-session');

app.use(
  session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: process.env.SECRET_SESSION_KEY,
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const strategy = new LocalStrategy(
  { usernameField: 'user' },
  (user, password, next) => {
    const adminDetails = {
      username: 'admin',
      password: 'admin',
    };

    if (user === adminDetails.username && password === adminDetails.password) {
      next(null, adminDetails);
    }

    next(null, false);
  }
);

passport.serializeUser((userobj, done) => {
  done(null, userobj);
});

passport.deserializeUser((userObj, done) => {
  done(null, userobj);
});

passport.use(strategy);

const checkAuthenthicated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }

  //If not authenthicated
  res.redirect('/login');
};

/************************
 * Receives the login form data and proceeds with the authentication
 ****/
app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/admin');
  });

  //If login fails
  res.json({ error: 'Wrong username or password!' });
});

//-------------Router functions for admin area-----------------------
app.get('/admin', checkAuthenthicated, (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'Success!' });
});

//------------App ports functions------------------------------------
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3008;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Here is my react code: -

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';

import {
  Input,
  Button,
  CircularProgress,
  Box,
  FormLabel,
  FormControl,
  Heading,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import styles from './styles/login.module.css';

import { login } from './service/login';

const LoginArea = () => {
  const loginInput = useRef();
  const passwordInput = useRef();

  //Keeps the track of the loading spinner
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  //shows error message
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  //Submit login form to the server
  const submitLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Start loading spinner
    setLoading(true);

    const loginResult = await login(
      loginInput.current.value,
      passwordInput.current.value
    );

    if (loginResult.data.error) {
      setErrorMessage(loginResult.data.error);
      setLoading(false);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setErrorMessage('');
      }, 5000);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Heading as='h1' size='3xl' isTruncated marginBottom='20px' color='white'>
        TastyBurger Inc.
      </Heading>
      <Box
        w='500px'
        borderWidth='2px'
        borderRadius='lg'
        p='10'
        fontWeight='bold'
        bg='cyan.50'
      >
        {errorMessage}
        <FormControl isRequired>
          <FormLabel>Login Id:</FormLabel>
          <Input
            ref={loginInput}
            type='text'
            placeholder='Login ID'
            size='lg'
            bg='white'
          />
        </FormControl>
        <br />
        <FormControl isRequired>
          <FormLabel>Password:</FormLabel>
          <Input
            ref={passwordInput}
            type='password'
            placeholder='Password'
            size='lg'
            bg='white'
          />
        </FormControl>
        <br />
        <FormControl isRequired>
          <Button
            type='submit'
            onClick={(e) => submitLogin(e)}
            colorScheme='blue'
          >
            {loading ? (
              <CircularProgress isIndeterminate size='24px' color='teal' />
            ) : (
              'Login'
            )}
          </Button>
        </FormControl>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginArea;
```

Comment: does it make a request on submit?

Comment: Yes, it's receiving input.

Comment: please add some screenshots of what backend receives from the api